# how to solve Tree.read(): expected u')' but got u'end-of-string' Error ? (NLTK)

Tags: nltk

I am trying to import text file then use:

```
 import codecs
 import re
 from nltk.tree import Tree
 string1=codecs.open(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tree2.txt','r','utf-8')
 txt2=string1.read()

 ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring (txt2)
```

but I got the following error :

```
 Tree.read(): expected u')' but got u'end-of-string'
```

Note : there is no error with content of this file becouse the program works
 correctly when I treat it as string like :

```
 txt2=unicode("""(S (w) (VP (VERB_PERFECT g) ))""",'utf-8')
 ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring (txt2)
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tested if `string1.read() == u"(S (w) (VP (VERB_PERFECT g) ))"`?

Comment: When you open the file in an editor, do you see two parens at the end?

Comment: yes , I'm sure the brackets are correct

Comment: Well, what's the difference then between the string literal and the string obtained from reading the file?

Comment: I used the string and imported `nltk.tree`'s ParentedTree and it seems to work fine with the string definition `(S (w) (VP (VERB_PERFECT g) ))`. Can you `print` the `txt2` variable that is not working?

Comment: Nevertheless, try `print(txt2)` for the `txt2` of your *first* snippet. I suspect you'll be surprised.

Comment: it  works with print(txt2), but it doesn't  with  ptree = ParentedTree.fromstring (txt2)   and I am sure the content is the same in both ways  : (S (w) (VP (VERB_PERFECT g) ))

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

I replaced /, (, ), { and } by "" in the tree string. Because it has their own meaning in the chunk tree string.

I had the same error in google colab pasted below:

```
ValueError: Tree.read(): expected ')' but got 'end-of-string' at index 4233. "...N) '/'')"
```

Have a nice day!